# Google Analytics events tracking fails for some submissions

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using Google Tag Manager on our website and through it I am sending events to Google Analytics once a form is submitted. The following code is just simply printed together with the submission confirmation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    sendGA('form_submit_completed', '{form_id}', '{form_sender}');
});
```

And the `sendGA` function is defined as follows.

```
function sendGA(anec, anea, anel) {

   if(typeof dataLayer === 'undefined') {
    console.log('Google analytics undefined, aren\'t you logged in?');
    return;
   }

   dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'ga_custom_event',
    'ga_anec': anec,
    'ga_anea': anea,
    'ga_anel': anel
   });

   console.log('ga_sent: {anec: ' + anec + ', anea: ' + anea + ', anel: ' + anel + '}');
}
```

When comparing data from Google Analytics with the submissions recorded in our database I can see that some submissions just do not get recorded in Google Analytics. I haven't been able to replicate this in any browser myself.

Does anyone have a clue what might cause this behaviour? I know that all the operations are asynchronous so sometimes the request just might not get through if the user leaves the page right away. But in the last week this happened to ~10% of all the submissions which is quite high to be caused by this.

Updated source code still having 10% dropoff:

```
function sendGA(anec, anea, anel)
{
    anec = anec || "empty_anec";
    anea = anea || "empty_anea";
    anel = anel || "empty_anel";
    let loggedIn = false;

    if(typeof window.dataLayer === 'undefined') {
        console.log('Google analytics undefined, aren\'t you logged in?');
        loggedIn = true;
    }

    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    window.dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'ga_custom_event',
        'ga_anec': anec,
        'ga_anea': anea,
        'ga_anel': anel
    });

    if(!loggedIn)
        console.log('ga_sent: {anec: ' + anec + ', anea: ' + anea + ', anel: ' + anel + '}');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be some sort of race condition. If GTM was loaded after this DOM ready code fires, your code will not attempt the tracking (as per your `typeof dataLayer === 'undefined'` check).

In practice, there's no need to worry about the timing in this case, as the dataLayer is a message queue. Even if it does not yet exist (i.e. GTM hasn't loaded), you can still push things onto it and your tags will fire when GTM catches up.

Try revising to the following:

```
function sendGA(anec, anea, anel) {

   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   window.dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'ga_custom_event',
    'ga_anec': anec,
    'ga_anea': anea,
    'ga_anel': anel
   });

   console.log('ga_sent: {anec: ' + anec + ', anea: ' + anea + ', anel: ' + anel + '}');
}
```

If you still see missing data after this change, is it possible that there are also missing variables? If you don't have values for the Event Category or Event Action (Event Action being the variable in your case), the event hit will not be valid and will be ignored during collection by Google Analytics.

*Side note: if the {form_sender} variable is the user's email address or other personal information, you'll want to avoid collecting this as it's against the GA terms of service to capture personally identifiable information (PII).*

*https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795983?hl=en*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is always one of the "not loaded yet" issues, right? I have also added "default" values for Event Category and Event Action so this will also show up if anything is wrong there. {form_sender} is a response ID, hopefully that is alright. I will get back here in a week and confirm your answer. Thanks.

Comment: So after a week of running on the improved source code I can still see about 10% of not recorder events. We also have tracking of the submit buttons click enabled and I cannot even see those for these submissions. Is it possible/probable that those users just have blocked cookies/GA at all? @CVM I updated the question with current source code.

Comment: I just noticed that the the ratio is much higher. For one of our forms none of 5 submissions showed up in Google Analytics. When I try to submit the form myself everything works just fine.